# JuiceUI and AjaxToolkit produce runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, juice-ui

I have following code in an aspx-Page with Masterpage:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#_Default').droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                debugger;
                var sender = ui.draggable;
                var pageId = '<%=  Page.UniqueID %>';
                __doPostBack('<%=TriggerDraggable.UniqueID%>', 
                  'Draggable#' + sender[0].id);
            }
        });
        $('#_Source').droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                debugger;
                var sender = ui.draggable;
                var pageId = '<%=  Page.UniqueID %>';
                __doPostBack('<%=TriggerDraggable.UniqueID%>', 
                  'Selected#' + sender[0].id);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything is fine if the page doesn't contain Ajax-Toolkit controls - but if there is e.g. a `ConfirmButtonExtender` i get the above mentioned error.

So it seems that the ajax toolkit somehow disposes this functionality.
That's why i inserted following tags in front of my actual script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/amplify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/juice.js"></script>
```

This prevents the error and I'm also able to drag some generated elements, but now the drop event is never called - which worked before.

Is there a way to ensure that my script is called first, prior the function calls of the AJAX toolkit? Or am I missing further script references?

Both are needed, the AJAX toolkit as well as the JuiceUI.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no JS script error in browser console? In above script, do you mean to use uniqueid and clientid in same code at two separate places? i.e.  `var pageId = '<%=  Page.UniqueID %>';` and  `var pageId = '<%=  Page.ClientID %>';`